# PowerShell access properties of [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, com

I am using PowerShell to automate IE as a com object.  At one point, I select an object and store it in the variable $productImages with this line:

```
$productImages = $ieInner.document.getElementById("product-image").getElementsByTagName("img")
```

After this, $productImages is an object with many properties. If you just type $productImages at the prompt, you'll get dozens, such as:

[image: Just a few of the properties of the object returned]

$productImages.length is 1.  In a previous version of this script (which works), my selector returned many objects and I added the src of all of them to an array. This selector only returns one, but $productImages.src is an invalid command.  I don't understand how to get the src URL of the product, that's my ultimate goal.

Comment: what about `$productImages[0].src`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to view the type of `$productImages`. In this case, I believe it is an array with one element, as you can access the length property.

```
$productImages.GetType()
```

The way you will access anything for an array is to use the below format:

```
$productImages[index].property
```

In your case the **required script** should be:

```
$productImages[0].src
```

Let us know if you get a different value for the GetType for your variable.

Comment: GetType() confirms that $productImages is a ComObject basetype of "System.MarshalByRefObject"

$productImages.length shows 1 as you expect.

But $productImages[0].src returns nothing

If I proceed with these lines I can get the src into another array and finally access it    $imgArray = @()
    foreach($img in $productimages) { $imgArray = $imgArray + $img.src }
    $imgURL = $imgArray[0]
    $imgURL = $productImages | select * | ForEach-Object { $_.src }

    $savePath = $saveLocation+$productName+".jpg"
    Start-BitsTransfer $imgURL $savePath